# CSS psuedo:element hover effect is not working correctly

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm using CSS to `ease-in-out` some text when a particular `psudeo:element` is hovered.

The code below is selecting the parent of the `.description` element I want to show on hover, however the hover effect is happening before I want it to.

```
.grid-item:hover .description {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

When the cursor is a few centimetres above the parent element, the hover state is triggered. I believe this may be a problem with the padding/margins of this element. I've tried many things with no luck.

Here is the [full code](https://codepen.io/jordan_miguel/pen/GvLXaM?editors=1100).

Gently hover a little bit over each image to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the CSS selector that shows the text on hover. At the moment, it is triggered when the parent of `.image`  (i.e. `.grid-item`) is hovered. Instead, if you set it as follows, it will be triggered when the div containing the image is hovered.

```
.image:hover + .description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here's the updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEWmEw?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

@Jordan Miguel, you're right. It's the padding, as well as the content itself.

[image]

If you crack open the dev tools for the browser of you choice (I'm using Chrome's in the picture), you can probably find a tool that will show the box model for a particular CSS element. When selecting your element, you can see the padding on the right and left side that trigger `hover`.

On the left hand pane of the tools, you can see the element selected as well as the stylings that have been applied. From here you can figure out what you'll need to change in order to get the behavior you expect.

Comment: yeah I actually done that before I asked the question, playing around with the paddings/margin didn't work. The correct answer is below.